# Изменение класса в OpenJDK и последующая сборка в jar (Eclipse)

Tags: java, openjdk

Здравствуйте нужна помощь с редактированием класса в библиотеке java
Просто не совсем понимаю как настроить Eclipse под всё это дело.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так (сам не проверял): найти файл `jar`, в котором находится нужный класс, декомпилировать его, внести необходимые изменения и собрать обратно.

Но лучше (это проверял): найти исходный код нужной библиотеки и изменения вносить в него, потом собрать файл `jar` и заменить им существующий (переименовать в `*.jar.old`).